# Extreme ends of normal distribution with uneven percentage of two groups

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, population

If there are two groups of people A and B which are both normally distributed around the same mean, and 80% of the total group is of type A and 20% is of type B, I know that if I randomly sample from the overall group that my random sample would have the same 80/20 breakdown. However, if I select from only the top .3%, what would the break down be from that new group? Would it still be 80% A and 20% B? Or would the breakdown skew more highly towards group A as the outliers become more extreme?

Comment: It depends on the standard deviations of the groups: what are you assuming about those?

Comment: Assume they are the same

Comment: Then your populations are indistinguishable: you have specified that they have identical characteristics.  Any reason that might suggest group A is over-represented in *any* set -- not just a top quantile -- would apply equally well to group B, proving the answer remains 80/20% no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal E$ be any event (a collection of numbers in whose probability you are interested).  Let $p_A$ be the chance that someone in group $A$ is in $\mathcal E$ and let $p_B$ be the chance for someone in group $B.$  The *odds* of being in $A$ and $\mathcal E,$ compared to being in $B$ and $\mathcal E,$ therefore is

$$\operatorname{odds}(A) = \frac{p_A}{p_B}.$$

The *prior odds* of $A$ is the original proportion, $80\%/20\% = 4.$  **Bayes' Theorem** says the odds (of $A$ compared to $B$) *conditional* on $\mathcal E$ is the product,

$$\operatorname{odds}(A\mid \mathcal E) = \frac{p_A}{p_B}\,\times\,\frac{80/100}{20/100}.$$

You may, of course, convert this to a conditional probability, because algebra tells us the probability $p$ corresponding to an odds $o$ is $o/(1+o).$  We have no need to do that here, because you have indicated that $A$ and $B$ have the same distribution, whence $p_A=p_B$ no matter what $\mathcal E$ might be, and therefore the conditional odds never differ from the original $80:20$ odds.